# c# override method for field in class

Tags: c#

I have following class:

```
 public class Invoice
    {
        public int Id_record { get; private set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; private set; }
    }
```

I would like to override method ToString() but only for field 'EmployeeID'. For example:

```
Invoice inv = new Invoice();
string s1 = inv.EmployeeID.ToString();  // returns: "Employee ID is: {0}."
string s2 = inv.Id_record.ToString(); // returns original value as string
```

Is it possible? I know that I could override method for classes, but only for field in classes...?

Comment: In order to override `.ToString()` for `int` you would need to have a class which inherits from `int`.  Which seems kind of strange... What other string representation could there *be* for an integer?

Comment: It's not possible without a new type because you aren't overriding an "instance" of a type, you are overriding the actual implementation for that type.  In this case, you'd have to do the override for `int` which would require subclassing int, which isn't possible since int is sealed.

Comment: @David you cant inherit from value types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id_record { get; private set; }
    public EmployeeID EmployeeID { get; private set; }
}

public struct EmployeeID
{
    // as per Eric Lippert's suggestion
    public EmployeeID(int id)
    {
        Value = id;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Employee ID is: {Value}.";
    }

    // as per Scott Chamberlain's suggestion
    public static implicit operator int(EmployeeID id)
    {
        return id.Value;
    }
}
```

and just use it like you were:

```
Invoice inv = new Invoice();
string s1 = inv.EmployeeID.ToString();  // returns: "Employee ID is: {0}."
string s2 = inv.Id_record.ToString(); // returns original value as string
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but I would make the value a read-only property set in the constructor. Mutable structs are a bad idea.

Comment: Ah, I've even read your blog post about that and I forgot... thanks for the good tip

Comment: Would you consider overloading all the arithmetic operators so that you can make the `Value` property private?

Comment: @botond.botos No, I don't think it's worth it mostly because it's a field for identification and you probably don't want most `int` operators for it, anyways.

Comment: I would add a implicit conversion to `int`, but overall, very good idea

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible, unless you want to create a custom `EmployeeID` type, and override the `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You call the ToString() method not on a **Property** of your class but on a **value** that is inside that property. That means, that you call ToString() of an **Int32** class. Hence, you can't override ToString() method for a single property.

What you can is to create custom field with getter only that will represent your field:

```
public string EmployeeIDTitle 
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("Employee ID is: {0}.", EmployeeID);
    }
}
```

And then use it in the places where you need it.